# Mysql: order a table using 2 columns in Descending order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i'm a bit stomped..

I'm trying to achieve a fairly simple logic..

I have a "user_sessions" table with log_in and log_out (int, epoch time stamps)

```
   userID | log_in | log_out
```

trying to show the RECENT activities, 
I need to list all the sessions in DESCENDING ORDER based on the LATEST ACTIVITY, and this could either be log_in or log_out.. and this is where i'm stomped. I tried different ORDER and SORT methods... I'm just not getting it.

Comment: what goes into log in/out? timestamps? a boolean flag?

Comment: just edited my post: they are int(10), epoch time stamps

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM user_sessions
ORDER BY GREATEST(log_in, log_out) DESC
```

Comment: wow, didn't know about this... *feeling stupid* 
thanks a bunch @barmar