# MYSQL Query - ORDER BY in UNION - Descending Order

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Using Microsoft Access.  Is it possible to sort the ORDER BY column as Descending?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table1.* FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT table2.* FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1
) DUMMY_ALIAS2
```

Comment: this has been answered here, use DESC after the fieldnames for descending http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618224/mysql-order-a-table-using-2-columns-in-descending-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - just add `desc` after the field name:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT table1.* FROM table1 ORDER BY table1.field1 DESC
) DUMMY_ALIAS1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT table2.* FROM table2 ORDER BY table2.field1 DESC
) DUMMY_ALIAS2
```